# findViewById not finding my button

Tags: android, button, findviewbyid

I'm new to Android programming, and I'm trying to make a simple button which displays a toast notification when clicked.

I tried to initialize a button called "button" in my MainActivity like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Click Me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Also, here is activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button1">

</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE: findViewById now works fine after importing android.R. However, this created a new error when I call setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

[image: Here is the new error]

Comment: Did you call `setContentView` first before getting that button? Post your `MainActivity` code

Comment: Posted. Sorry about the whole "Click Me" debacle

Comment: Is `strings.xml` the only place you define your button? Can we see `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: hold on... StackOverflow is saying my code isn't being formatted right. Sorry!

Comment: Sounds like your "R" file (found in your "gen" folder in your project's structure) isn't being re-generated correctly. The error you see is actually Eclipse's way of showing your errors in your source files, it hasn't any contact with Android yet.

Comment: Do you have import android.R; in package section?

Comment: I imported android.R and it fixed the issue. However, this gives me a new error. I've posted a screenshot of the new error, it happens when I call setContentView on R.layout.activity_main.

Answer (score 2):

Okay a bit of background here. strings.xml is for defining pieces of text. For instance the text that might go on a button (but this does not define the button itself).

The button is going to have to be defined in a layout file in the res/layout/ directory. Yours is likely called activity_main.xml.

You'll need to create a button element in this file and assign the id to something descriptive. This kind of id is what `findViewById` is going to search on.

An example:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/thebuttonsid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
```

You can get a handle to this button like so:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thebuttonsid);
```

Notice how I set the text to `@string/button1`? This is what the strings.xml file is for. However the layout files in the layout directory are where you define controls like buttons.

Comment: Additional note here -- your string should have a different Id than your button. Strings are not tied to a specific purpose and as such are kind of their own entities. Does that help at all?

Comment: Ok, I posted my activity_main.xml code and it looks good to me, but findViewById still isn't getting a handle to the button. Can you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, is clicking the button causing a crash? Is findViewById returning null? Is the toast just not appearing? Can you give me a bit more insight on what you are actually seeing on the device.

Comment: When I call "Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);" in MainActivity, the "button1" at the end of "R.id.button1" is highlighted in red, eclipse thinks it "cannot be resolved or is not a field." This means that it just can't find button1. I haven't tried running it yet, as it's not even compiling.

Comment: I've attached a pic of the compiler error when I try to call findViewById. Also everything in my activity_main.xml is posted.

Comment: Are all the files in your project saved to disk? If they have an asterisks next to them in the main window they need to be saved. Have you tried running "Project > Clean" in the main menu bar? Unfortunately I tried a demo project with your code and couldn't reproduce any problems.

Comment: Hi Darius, I fixed the button recognition problem by simply importing android.R. However, this gives me a new error when I call  setContentView on R.layout.activity_main. I posted a screenshot of this new error.

Answer (score 0):

The button's ID name is same to the button's text name. You'd better change any one to other name.It must be work.

Answer (score 0):

I would clean the project and build again. Or reimport the project. Eclipse is ... just hard to use. Try to use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When there is some "mismatch" with resources cleaning a project is a good advice. IN the past it was even more so.
Next what I would check if your resources compile as such. You might have an error somewhere in your resources, therefore the R does net get compiled and any reference to R.id.* is not valid.